# Catalog Search not working in magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

No search result in catalog search. I have reindex data still getting no result. When i look in data base, i found that my catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 table is empty. is there any issue with this?

Comment: I would retry running your indexer again also make sure you have full page cache flushed and finally make sure that attributes are set to searchable